# Creating HTML and Text version of entry via different templates

Tags: routes, routing

So I'm using Craft to create code to be pasted into a blast email program. My standard template is at the following:

```
newsletter/_entry
```

However, I'm having trouble getting the text version to display in any way. I tried creating the following folder structure which did not work (404).

```
newsletter/text/_entry
```

I tried using routes in the backend to do this, but does not work either. I know I must be missing something simple. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you planning to serve the text version?

Answer (score 1):

The issue may have to do with the extensions on the files in your template folder. By default, Craft only renders `.html` and `.txt` files. If you want Craft to also render `.txt` files, you could update the [defaultTemplateExtensions](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#defaultTemplateExtensions) config variable.  Adding something like this to your `general.php` would get `.txt` files rendering:

```
'defaultTemplateExtensions' => array('html', 'twig', 'txt')
```

If you want to access a `.txt` file without enabling it as a `defaultTemplateExtension`, you would have to access the template URL with the full file extension.

This URL would work out of the box:

```
/newsletter/entry.txt
```

This would only render `.html` or `.twig`:

```
/newsletter/entry
```

These defaults makes it a little harder to use a hidden template file such as `newsletter/_entry` for non-standard extensions. One work around would be to pass your ID as a parameter in the URL and manually grab it in your template code to determine what to do on the page.

This is an option:

```
/newsletter/entry.txt?id=123
```

---

As an alternative method, the plugin [Sprout Email](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/email) helps manage a lot of components of HTML and Text versions of email templates, and ships with a `Copy/Paste Mailer` which allows a user to copy and paste the HTML and Text versions of an email directly from a modal in the the Control Panel.

[image]